# A logic issue regarding a very simple solution that performs the factorizing function

Tags: c#, logic

This solution factorizes a number (numInput), it works perfectly well except for a logic error I can't seem to find no matter how much I track the solution. The logic error causes the returned result to be 0 no matter the value initialized for numInput.

```
using System;

namespace factorizer
{
     class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(factorialise());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int factorialise()
    {
        int numInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] number = new int[numInput];

        for (int i = 1; i < numInput; i++) //stores the (n-1)...(n-i) value for the number input'd in the array number[i]
        {
            number[i - 1] = numInput - i; //the element indicating the index number is 'i - 1' index values start from zero
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < number.Length; index++) //multiplies the element corresponding the index number with the number input'd
        {
            numInput = numInput * number[index];
        }

        return numInput;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: terminology error. "Factorize" means to compute the prime factors of an integer, or something like that. Factorial (n) = 1 x 2 x 3 x ... x (n-1) x n. Your factorial function is computing 0 x 1 x 2 x 3 x ... n. Get rid of the 0.

Comment: FYI, you may want to consider using `long` instead as the maximum integer factorial you'll be able to calculate is `12` before it overflows. EDIT: May also want to consider using `ulong` (or validate that a negative number was not inputted)

Answer (score 1):

Your last item in array stays uninitialized (i.e. equal to zero). Change items count:

```
int[] number = new int[numInput-1];
```

---

Also why not simply use for loop?

```
int result = 1;

for(int i = 1; i <= numInput; i++)
    result *= i;
```

And another sample just for fun

```
Enumerable.Range(1, numInput).Aggregate(1, (a,i) => a * i)
```

Comment: While we're talking about fun, why not make a lookup table that holds all possible factorials for `Int32`? `int[] factorialLookup = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600 }; int result = factorialLookup[numInput];` Super fast! :D

Comment: @ChrisSinclair agree, for integer values nothing can be faster :)